# .toggle() не перебирает функции, только прячет элемент

Tags: jquery

```
<a class="addToFav" href="#" >
    <i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
</a>
```

По нажатию на ссылку вызываем функцию:

```
$('.addToFav').click(
                function () {
                    $(this).toggle(
                            function () {
                                $(this).find('i').text('star');
                            },
                            function () {
                                $(this).find('i').text('star_border');
                            });
                }
        );
```

Вместо смены текста внутри `<i>` элемент прячется, получает display: none . Что не так?

Comment: Потому что функция toggle() скрывает, показывает элементы. Собственно это и происходит. Читайте документацию https://jquery-docs.ru/toggle/ . Опишите более подробно что требуется сделать, возможно помогут.

Comment: Я читал документацию и полагаю, что .toggle() скрывает/показывает элементы в том случае, если вызывается без аргументов. Если же ей в качестве аргументов передаются несколько функций, то .toggle() обеспечивает очередность их выполнения, в моем случае при нажатии на ссылку

Comment: Там может передаваться функция в качестве колбека. Т.е. она выполняется, при завершении анимации.

Comment: @Pavel, уже готов был с Вами согласиться, но в подтверждение своих же слов нашел вот этот пример: http://www.wisdomweb.ru/editor/wweditor.php?fname=jqd_toggle . Нас интересует первый абзац

Comment: Вы прикладываете пример с старой версией jquery. Поэтому данный функционал и не описан в доке, ибо его уже нет.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«The toggle() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, and removed in version 1.9.»

А для такой задачи даже jQuery не нужен, но всё же, можно организовать так:

```js
$('.addToFav').on('click', function() {
  var $i = $(this).find('i');
  var txt = ( $i.text() === "star" ) ? "star_border" : "star" ;
  $i.text( txt );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="addToFav" href="#">
  <i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
</a>
```

Перевод на "чистый" JS:

```js
let all = document.querySelectorAll('.addToFav');
for( let i = 0; i < all.length; i++ ){

  all[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
    let $i = this.querySelector('i');    
    $i.innerText = ($i.innerText === "star") ? "star_border" : "star";
  });

}
```

```html
<a class="addToFav" href="#">
  <i class="material-icons">star_border</i>
</a>
```

P.s.

```js
$('.addToFav').on('click', function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('v1');
});
```

```css
.addToFav .material-icons::before {
  content: "star";
}

.addToFav.v1 .material-icons::before {
  content: "star_border";
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<a class="addToFav" href="#">
  <i class="material-icons"></i>
</a>
```

или

```css
.toggle, .material-icons.hide { display: none; }

.toggle:checked ~ .material-icons { display: none; }
.toggle:checked ~ .material-icons.hide { display: inline; }
```

```html
<a class="addToFav" href="#">
  <label>
    <input class="toggle" type="checkbox">
    <i class="material-icons">star</i>
    <i class="material-icons hide">star_border</i>
  </label>
</a>
```

Comment: Стоит уточнить, что не сам метод устарел, а как раз его реализация с функциями. 

https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#toggle-function-function-removed

Answer (score 0):

Если вам надо меня текст и  обратно, то:

```
$('.addToFav').click(function(){
    if (!$(this).data('status')) {
         $(this).find('i').text('star');
         $(this).data('status', true);
   }else {
        $(this).find('i').text('star_border');
        $(this).data('status', false);
  }
}
);
```

Протестировать: https://jsfiddle.net/3mq2u7kp/

Решение взято с https://toster.ru/q/349505